# Split Pandas DF columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have the below DF I need to manipulate. The problem is the two tags columns can have either none, a Movie title or a Genre. I need to separate the Movie title and Genres into two new separate columns named Movie and Genre respectively and if either column contains none don't even evaluate it.

| VideoId | Tags1 | Tags2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | None | None |
| 3456 | Movie:Rocky | Genre:Drama |
| 5678 | Genre:Romance | Movie:Love Me |
| 7890 | Movie:Scream | Genre:Horror |
| 9012 | Movie:Shrek | None |

So if columns contains Movie: then split the and put the second item of the array into the new Movie Column. If it contains Genre then split and place it in the new Genre column.  I am getting an index out of range for the 'none' columns. And I think I have to reiterate thru each column again to find Genres that are in the Movies DF and vice-versa.

`Movies = df['Tags1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] if 'Movie' in x else x)`

`Genres = df['Tags2'].apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] if 'Genre' in x else x)`

The resulting DF should look like below:

| VideoId | Movie | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | None | None |
| 3456 | Rocky | Drama |
| 5678 | Love Me | Romance |
| 7890 | Scream | Horror |
| 9012 | Shrek | None |

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x.split(':')[1] if 'Genre:' in x or 'Movie:' in x else x)`

Comment: What happens if both Tags1, Tags2 column has Movie: or Genre: in the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution below uses [`.itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) to go through all cells and splits any cells [unless they're in the first columns] containing `:` into a key-value pair, so it should work for any number of tag-types and `Tags_` columns.

```py
# import pandas as pd
# df = pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909759')[0] # from your q

parse_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c[:4]=='Tags' or c=='VideoId'] # [filter]
max_cols = 2 # None # [ set None to include all columns ]

new_df = pd.DataFrame([{'VideoId':vi, **{k:v for k,v in [
    rv.split(':',1) for rv in row[:max_cols] if isinstance(rv,str) and ':' in rv
]}} for _, vi, *row in df[parse_cols].itertuples()])
# ]}} for vi, *row in df.itertuples()]) ## if df['VideoId'] is also df.index
```

<sub>**NOTE: Omit the `_,` part in *`...for _, vi, *row in...`* if `df['VideoId']` is also `df.index`.**</sub>

`new_df` should look like

> ```py
> ╒═══════════╤═════════╤═════════╕
> │   VideoId │ Movie   │ Genre   │
> ╞═══════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
> │      1234 │ None    │ None    │
> ├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
> │      3456 │ Rocky   │ Drama   │
> ├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
> │      5678 │ Love Me │ Romance │
> ├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
> │      7890 │ Scream  │ Horror  │
> ├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
> │      9012 │ Shrek   │ None    │
> ╘═══════════╧═════════╧═════════╛
> ```
>
> <sub>[Printed with `print(new_df.fillna('None').to_markdown(index=False, tablefmt='fancy_grid'))`.]</sub>

---

Btw, about

> <sup>*"What happens if both Tags1, Tags2 column has Movie: or Genre: in the same row?"*  -- [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75909759/split-pandas-df-columns-based-on-condition/75909936#comment133892091_75909759) by [SomeDude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410303/somedude)</sup>

In the case of this solution, the value from last column [`Tags2` in your sample data] will over-write any values with the same key from previous columns.

Comment: Yes. That's a problem. I simplified the data example above.  In reality, I could have Tags1,Tags2,Tags3.... and the Movie or Genre data could be in any one of the Tags columns.

Comment: @AlekseiWolff I thought that might be so, from what I remember of some other movie datasets. Did my answer work for your data btw?

Comment: It did work, since it created two column (movie, genre) as requested. But since there are other columns with embedded colons in it (i.e. urls,timestamps etc.) then it's creating a whole bunch of other columns I don't need. Is there a way to limit it to just columns named TagsN?

Comment: @AlekseiWolff sure, just limit them in the *`...for rv in row if...`* bit by using `row[:N]` to limit the **number** of columns, or just select the columns you want to parse with `df[parse_cols]` in *`...for _, vi, *row in df.itertuples()...`* [I've edited my answer]

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function to `apply()` on columns `Tags1` and `Tags2`:

```
import pandas as pd

# Extract the movie/genre from interest columns
def get_movie_genre(row, cols):
    # Default value
    movie = 'None'
    genre = 'None'
    # Loop through the columns
    for col_name in cols:
        # Check for none
        if row[col_name].lower() != 'none':
            # Get values for either movie or genre
            name, val = row[col_name].split(':')
            if name.lower() == 'movie':
                movie = val
            elif name.lower() == 'genre':
                genre = val

    # Set values to columns
    row[cols[0]] = movie
    row[cols[1]] = genre

    return row

# My definition of your example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Videold': [1234, 3456, 5678, 7890, 9012],
                    'Tags1': ['None', 'Movie:Rocky', 'Genre:Romance', 'Movie:Scream', 'Movie:Shrek'],
                    'Tags2': ['None', 'Genre:Drama', 'Movie:Love Me', 'Genre:Horror', 'None']})

# Cols we are interested in apply get_movie_genre from rows
cols_of_interest = ['Tags1', 'Tags2']

# Create Movie and Genre colums from the return values of apply by row
df[['Movies', 'Genre']] = df[cols_of_interest].apply(lambda x: get_movie_genre(x, cols_of_interest), axis=1)

# Drop Tags1 and Tags2
df = df.drop(cols_of_interest, axis=1)
```

Contents of `df` after manipulation:

```
   Videold   Movies    Genre
0     1234     None     None
1     3456    Rocky    Drama
2     5678  Love Me  Romance
3     7890   Scream   Horror
4     9012    Shrek     None
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have Movie or Genre both in the same row for Tags1, Tags2

(actually it should work even if you have, but there won't be space between two Movies or Genres in that case)

A fast solution would be to use `Series.str` methods like `str.extract`:

```
df["Genre"] = df["Tags1"].str.extract(r"^\s*Genre\s*:\s*(.*?)$").fillna("") + df[
    "Tags2"
].str.extract(r"^\s*Genre\s*:\s*(.*?)$").fillna("")
df["Movie"] = df["Tags1"].str.extract(r"^\s*Movie\s*:\s*(.*?)$").fillna("") + df[
    "Tags2"
].str.extract(r"^\s*Movie\s*:\s*(.*?)$").fillna("")
print(df)

   VideoId          Tags1          Tags2    Genre    Movie
0     1234           None           None                  
1     3456    Movie:Rocky    Genre:Drama    Drama    Rocky
2     5678  Genre:Romance  Movie:Love Me  Romance  Love Me
3     7890   Movie:Scream   Genre:Horror   Horror   Scream
4     9012    Movie:Shrek           None             Shrek
```